# How to make specific column of the Kendo Grid editable?

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I made the fields in the Kendo Grid editable by the following code:

```
Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.lstResend)
                 .Name("ResendFlowGride")

                     .Columns(
                                column =>
                                {
                                    column.Bound(e => e.FLOW_ID).Title("Id").Hidden(true);
                                    column.Bound(e => e.GROUP_ID).Title("Group Id").Hidden(true);
                                    column.Bound(e => e.GROUP_NAME).Title("Group Name");
                                    column.Bound(e => e.ITEM_ID).Title("Item Id").Hidden(true);
                                    column.Bound(e => e.ITEM_NAME).Title("Item Name");
                                    column.Bound(e => e.ITEM_VALUE).Title("Item Value");
                                    //  column.Bound(e => e.ITEM_VALUE).Ed


                                }
                        )
                     .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                     .DataSource(datasource => datasource.Ajax()

                     .Model(model =>
                     {
                         model.Id(p => p.ITEM_ID);
                         model.Field(p => p.ITEM_ID).Editable(false);
                         model.Field(p => p.GROUP_ID).Editable(false);
                         model.Field(p => p.GROUP_NAME).Editable(false);
                         model.Field(p => p.ITEM_NAME).Editable(false);
                         model.Field(p => p.ITEM_VALUE).Editable(true);
                     })


                     )
```

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult SendResendFile(int Flow_Id, int RegID, int ResendId, string Condition, string GroupWhere)
        {

            RegistrationHeaderDetails RegHD = new RegistrationHeaderDetails();


            string strMsg = string.Empty;

            using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                try
                {


                    _repository.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec PROC_SEND_RESEND_FILE {0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}", RegID, Flow_Id, Convert.ToInt32(Session["userid"]), ResendId, GroupWhere, Condition);


                    IEnumerable<ResendFlowDetail> IResendFlowDetail = _repository.Context.Database.SqlQuery<ResendFlowDetail>("PROC_GET_RESEND_FLOW @REG_ID = {0} ", RegID).ToList().AsQueryable();
                    RegHD.lstResendFlowDetail = IResendFlowDetail.ToList();

                    IEnumerable<ResendFlow> IResendFlow = _repository.Context.Database.SqlQuery<ResendFlow>("PROC_GET_DATA_RESEND_FILE @REGID = {0}, @FLOWID = {1} ", RegID, 0).ToList().AsQueryable();
                    RegHD.lstResend = IResendFlow.ToList();

                    IEnumerable<DataFlow> DataflowDetails = _repository.Context.Database.SqlQuery<DataFlow>("PROC_GET_FILES_DATAFLOW @RegistrationId = {0}", RegID).ToList().AsQueryable();
                    RegHD.DataFlow = DataflowDetails.ToList();


                    transaction.Complete();


                    if (Flow_Id == 1)
                    {
                        strMsg = "Flow D0055 Send Successfully";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strMsg = "File Send Successfully";

                    }

                }
```

I am editing the fields and sending the flow by clicking on send flow button which creates the file.

But whatever I am editing, it is not getting reflected to updated data. What am I doing wrong?

Suppose item value is SP04 and I am updating it to SP03. I am clicking send flow button. File is created but with the SP04.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand. Where is your button to update? What do you get in (I am assuming) your controller method?

Comment: @JamesS i am using keno for the first time.Should i use update action in kendo?

Comment: If you are wanting to update the selected row. I would consider using a datasource `update` action which would call the controller method. Along with this you could also add/ lookup hwo to use the `.Command` functions for the column. What does `datasource.Ajax()` currently do? Where is it going?

Comment: @JamesS kindly see  image link   https://ibb.co/f8g45nB

Comment: Could you update the question with where the button goes?

Comment: @JamesS i have updated the code

Comment: @JamesS So on button click,it will call the above controller..

Comment: I've posted a detailed response below which is an ASP.NET-MVC implementation of a Kendo grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading over what you have done. I would suggest the following:

```
Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.lstResend)
    .Name("ResendFlowGride")
    .Columns(
        column =>
        {
            column.Bound(e => e.FLOW_ID).Title("Id").Hidden(true);
            column.Bound(e => e.GROUP_ID).Title("Group Id").Hidden(true);
            column.Bound(e => e.GROUP_NAME).Title("Group Name");
            column.Bound(e => e.ITEM_ID).Title("Item Id").Hidden(true);
            column.Bound(e => e.ITEM_NAME).Title("Item Name");
            column.Bound(e => e.ITEM_VALUE).Title("Item Value");
            //  column.Bound(e => e.ITEM_VALUE).Ed
            columns.Command(commands =>
            {
                commands.Edit();
                commands.Destroy();
            }).Width(200);
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .DataSource(datasource => datasource
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model =>
                 {
                     model.Id(p => p.ITEM_ID);
                     model.Field(p => p.ITEM_ID).Editable(false);
                     model.Field(p => p.GROUP_ID).Editable(false);
                     model.Field(p => p.GROUP_NAME).Editable(false);
                     model.Field(p => p.ITEM_NAME).Editable(false);
                     model.Field(p => p.ITEM_VALUE).Editable(true);
                 })
            .Create(create => create.Action("//ControllerMethod", "//Controller"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("//ControllerMethod", "//Controller"))
            //.Read(read => read.Action("//ControllerMethod", "//Controller")) // If you wanted to read the data in here instead of passing it in above
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("//ControllerMethod", "//Controller"))
        )
}
```

This does the following:

- This adds a tool bar to grid header that allows you to create new rows in the table.
- Allows you to update/ delete a row
- Allows you to save

Controller methods should be as follows:

CREATE:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> //MethodName ([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, // gridmodel model)
    {
        bool result = false;

        // You can check if the model state is valid
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do whatever
        }

        return Json(new[] { model}.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

UPDATE

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> //MethodName([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, // gridmodel model)
    {
        bool wasSuccess = false;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do whatever
        }

        return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

DELETE

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> //MethodName ([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, //gridmodel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && model!= null)
        {
            // Do whatever
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Of course you could return something here as well.

The above is an MVC implementation of a kendo grid

Comment: i am getting txns as null..  public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<ResendFlow> txns)
        {}

Comment: @chetankambli It won't be an IEnumerable as we're working with a row at a time here. it would just be `ResendFlow txns`

Comment: Can you tell me how to display error messages from controller in kendo?

Comment: @chetankambli To display an error message from the controller you can add an event to the grid such as `.Events(e => e.Error("//name it something like gridName_OnError"))` to follow the naming conventions. In your controller method where you want the error to show if something goes wrong, add a modelstate error such as `ModelState.AddModelError("updateerrors", "Error when saving information")` and return the modelstate in the response with the request.

Comment: can you help me with this link? Thanks for your detailed explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908385/how-to-display-validation-error-message-in-controller-using-kendo-grid